# highstock: PlotlLines text legend does not work when having 2 x-axes

Tags: highcharts, legend, lines, axes

I have 2 x-axes in a chart and would like to plot 2 y-axes lines. However, the text legend of the plotted lines in the y-axes are printed on top of the chart and not right to the plotlines.

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/joe992005/s48gV/

```
$(function() {  

    var seriesOptions = [],
        yAxisOptions = [],
        seriesCounter = 0,
        names = ['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'GOOG'],     
        colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;

    $.each(names, function(i, name) {

         $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename='+ name.toLowerCase() +'-c.json&callback=?',  function(data) {

            seriesOptions[i] = {
                name: name,             
                data: data
            };

            seriesCounter++;

            if (seriesCounter == names.length) {
                createChart();
            }

        });

    });             

    function createChart() {

  window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({     

                      chart: {
                             renderTo : 'container',                 
        },

         yAxis: [{

                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 2,
                    color: 'silver'
                },{
                    value : 600,
                    color : 'green',
                    dashStyle : 'shortdash',
                    width : 2,
                    label : {

                    align: 'right',
                    y: 12,
                    x: 0,
                        text : 'test bla bla bla 1'
                    }
                }, {
                    value : 250,
                    color : 'red',
                    dashStyle : 'shortdash',
                    width : 2,
                    label : {
                        align: 'left',
                    y: 12,
                    x: 0,
                        text : 'test  bla bla bla 2'
                    }
                }]
            }],


    xAxis: [{

        }, {
              linkedTo: 0
        }],

            series: seriesOptions


    });

    }

});
```

Can anybody help me on on that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug, reported to our developers here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3000